# Css with jquery selector not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this big prob with my code, Im trying to implement a button which execute the the function createElements, which basically create new elements (in my case it creates input file) I have successfully make it upload different photos. The only problem that I have now is that with the css. Whenever a user browsed a photo and hover it a remove text should be present so as to remove the corresponding images. But it is not working as expected. Please run the snippet you will understand it better. The remove is only shown on the first created elements. Can someone help?

```js
function createElements() {
    const userQuestions = document.getElementById('userQuestions');
    userQuestions.insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend', '<center><div class="uploader" onclick="selectFile(this)"></div><input type="file" name="userprofile_picture" accept="image/*" onchange="handleImage(this)" />');
}

///code for image
function selectFile(uploader) {
    uploader.nextSibling.click();
}

///Code to preview image 
function handleImage(input) {
    if (input.files.length) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            input.previousSibling.innerHTML =
                '<img width="100%" height="100%" class="image" src="' + e.target.result + '"/><div class="middle"><div class="text">Remove</div></div>';
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```css
.uploader:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.uploader:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="createElements()">click</button>
        <div id="userQuestions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Please note that the createElements() cannot be omitted**

Comment: You need to loop over `input.files`, and create a `FileReader` at each step of the loop. You are only using `input.files[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I did fix your CSS, using flex, I suggest you look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```js
function createElements() {
    const userQuestions = document.getElementById('userQuestions');
    userQuestions.insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend', '<center><div class="uploader" onclick="selectFile(this)"></div><input type="file" name="userprofile_picture" accept="image/*" onchange="handleImage(this)" />');
}

///code for image
function selectFile(uploader) {
    uploader.nextSibling.click();
}

///Code to preview image 
function handleImage(input) {
    if (input.files.length) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            input.previousSibling.innerHTML =
                '<img width="100%" height="100%" class="image" src="' + e.target.result + '"/><div class="middle"><div class="text">Remove</div></div>';
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```css
.uploader{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.uploader:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex
}

.uploader:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head><head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="createElements()">click</button>
        <div id="userQuestions"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it work! I definitely need to look into flexbox, because this thing is amazing  !